# How can I push CI/CD pipeline job outputs (artifacts) to my GitLab repo?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have a python script in my repo that connects to a database and processes the results into files that are saved in the repository. Normally, I run this script locally; e.g., `python get_and_process_db_data.py`. But I want this process to automatically occur in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline. I can't find any insight on how to take output data from a CI/CD job (artifacts) and save it, or push it, to the GitLab repo.

---

Here's an example that demonstrates my repository contents:

```bash
Project/
├───Data/
│       data_file.txt
│       extra_data.txt
│       processed_data.txt
│
└───Script/
        get_and_process_db_data.py
```

When I push to the GitLab repo I want a CI/CD pipeline job to automatically run `get_and_process_db_data.py` and store the outputs (artifacts) to the repo; i.e., replace the current contents in the `Data/` folder with updated outputs. How can I do this?

I haven't found any way to make changes to a GitLab repo via CI/CD pipeline jobs.